# global constants in a separate file other than settings.py in django?

Tags: django, constants, global

I expect to define a lot of constants in a project.
I don't want to pollute settings.py with them.
(as mentioned [Defining Constants in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042407/defining-constants-in-django))

Where/How do you define global constants in django other than settings.py file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django `settings.py` is a good place to have your constants defined. Other option is to write your own template context processor. But just have a separate file where you define all of your constants and import them in settings file in this way your settings file will not be polluted:

**settings.py**

```
# other settings
# ----------

try:
    form my_constants import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Comment: That looks better. can I do something like `import my_constants` in settings.py and use settings.my_constants.SOME_CONSTANT? in order to prevent name clash?

Comment: No this will not work `settings.my_constants.SOME_CONSTANT` it will be accessed as `settings.SOME_CONSTANT`. To avoid name clash you can have dictionary of constants in `my_constants` in this way only dictionary will be there and then access your constants from dictionary, e.g. `settings.MY_DICT['MY_CONSTANT_A']` where `MY_DICT` is defined in `my_constants` file.