# how do I add homepage to Django sitemap?

Tags: python, django, sitemap, django-sitemaps

The sitemap given sitemap class generates a sitemap at the location, `example.com/sitemap.xml`

from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from blog.models import Entry
for the given Sitemap class,

```
class BlogSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "never"
    priority = 0.5

    def items(self):
        return Entry.objects.filter(is_draft=False)

    def lastmod(self, obj):
        return obj.pub_date
```

The generated sitemap contains all the objects in the Blog model but not the content outside of the Queryset, How do I add the homepage to the sitemap?

urls

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from blog.sitemaps import BlogSitemap


sitemaps = {
    'blog': BlogSitemap
}
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', 'blog.views.home'),
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps},
        name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
]
```

Comment: this could be helpful -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/21493335/1407478

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a [sitemap for static views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#sitemap-for-static-views):

```
class StaticViewSitemap(sitemaps.Sitemap):
    priority = 0.5
    changefreq = 'daily'

    def items(self):
        return ['home']

    def location(self, item):
        return reverse(item)
```

This assumes you have url pattern for the homepage with name "home"

```
url(r'^$', views.homepage, name="home"),
```

Then add the `StaticViewSitemap` to the `sitemaps` dict in your urls.py.

```
sitemaps = {
    'blog': BlogSitemap,
    'static': StaticViewSiteMap,
}
```